# Searching annotation in mapkit

Tags: iphone, xcode, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

im trying to add a search bar to the current mapkit im doing.

The search bar will be able to search for the different location name (annotations on the map) in a table view.

When users click on a certain cell it will direct them to the specific annotation on the map.

Any ideas on how to do it? I googled for answers, but most of the tutorial teach us on searching through sqlite and so on.

Answer (score 0):

@funatsg i suggest u to take the data from a a particular `index` from you `UITableView` search result and take that data to your `mapView` and then start searching for that paticular location in a map (eg:-by giving that string to google map) and you will get the particular location.
I would like to suggest a link to you which is some how similar to your condition.....see how the map is searching the data of the text from `UITextField`..try this [link](http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial/#comment-5286)

Hope it will help u and solve your problem!!!